# simplexml addChild in a certain tag

Tags: php, xml, session, simplexml

I want to add a child for a cetrain user.

```
        $file = simplexml_load_file('gebruikers.xml');

        $user = $file->$_SESSION["S_voornaam"];
        $usercord = $user->addChild('coordinaat');
        $usercord->addChild('1',$_SESSION["S_coordinaat"]);

        file_put_contents('gebruikers.xml', $file->asXML());
```

This is my xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<gebruikers>
<user>
    <voornaam>admin</voornaam>
    <achternaam>web</achternaam>
    <wachtwoord>1234</wachtwoord>
</user>
<user>
    <voornaam>jef</voornaam>
    <achternaam>gys</achternaam>
    <wachtwoord>1234</wachtwoord>
</user>
</gebruikers>
```

Example:

When the $_SESSION["S_voornaam"] = admin
and $_SESSION["S_coordinaat"] = (51.2241558, 4.41293399999995)
This is the result i want.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<gebruikers>
<user>
    <voornaam>admin</voornaam>
    <achternaam>web</achternaam>
    <wachtwoord>1234</wachtwoord>
            <coordinaat>
                <1>(51.2241558, 4.41293399999995)</1>
            </coordinaat>

</user>
<user>
    <voornaam>jef</voornaam>
    <achternaam>gys</achternaam>
    <wachtwoord>1234</wachtwoord>
</user>
</gebruikers>
```

Answer (score 0):

Example;

```
$user = $file->xpath('//user[voornaam = "name"]')[0];
```